# JOptionPane Multidimensional Array output

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Ok say I have Multidimensional array that I want to display in `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`. I know that when using `System.out.println`, you use a for loop. However the array size is determined by the user input, therefore I have to use a incrementor.

For example: `userinput[k]` next to `usernumber[k]` then the next row would be `userinput[k+1]` next to `usernumber[k+1]`

The trouble I am having is that by using my loop, it does each set one at a time in separate windows and not all together in a table in one window.

```
for (int k = 0; k < userinput.length; k++){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, userinput[k]);
}

for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, usernumber[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Build your output into a single `String`.

You can use `html` tags to provide additional formatting

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
sb.append("<html><table>");
for (int ui = 0; ui = < userinput.length; ui++) {
    sb.append("<tr><td>");
    sb.append(userinput[ui]);
    sb.append("</td>");
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){
        sb.append("<td>");
        sb.append(usernumber[k]);
        sb.append("</td>");
    }
    sb.append("</tr>");
}
sb.append("</table></html>");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
```

Comment: I'm messing around with what you provided. Is there a reason why it says it can't find the symbol sb.toString when compiling?

Comment: Sorry, missed the `()` - `toString` is a method :P - I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StringBuilder` and concatenate each element of the array into a display message,