# How to use arrayList to store info from a JFrame and display it in a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, superclass

My assignment requires me to use an arrayList to take the user selections of each order and display them in an Order Summary JOptionPane.  Do I have to create a new class for the arrayList.  We learned them without using GUIs so I am unsure on how to get it to display in the order summary for each order.  For instance, if someone picked a sub type how would I get the type and price, store it in the arrayList, and display it in the order summary.  If I was explained how to do one then I could figure out the rest.

EDITED

I tried to get the "toppings" the same way as the other options but it wouldn't  work.  How do you get this to work with a JCheckBox.   Also,  how do I do it for numbers to get the price?  You can see in my code that I am trying a way with a case/switch.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Subway extends JFrame {

    private String[] breadNames = {"9-grain Wheat", "Italian", "Honey Oat",
        "Herbs and Cheese", "Flatbread"};
    private String[] subTypes = {"Oven Roasted Chicken - $3.50",
        "Meatball Marinara - $4.50", "Cold Cut Combo - $4.00",
        "BLT - $3.75", "Blackforest Ham - $4.00", "Veggie Delight - $2.50"};
    private String[] cheesetypes = {
        "Cheddar", "American", "Provolone", "Pepperjack"};
    private String[] size = {"6 inch", "Footlong"};
    private String[] toasted = {"Yes", "No"};
    private JTextField jtfname = new JTextField(10);
    private JComboBox<String> jcbBread = new JComboBox<String>(breadNames);
    private JComboBox<String> jcbtype = new JComboBox<String>(subTypes);
    private JComboBox<String> jcbcheese = new JComboBox<String>(cheesetypes);
    private JButton jbtExit = new JButton("EXIT");
    private JButton jbtAnother = new JButton("Next Order");
    private JButton jbtSubmit = new JButton("SUBMIT");
    private JComboBox<String> jcbSize = new JComboBox<String>(size);
    private JComboBox<String> jcbToasted = new JComboBox<String>(toasted);
    private JCheckBox jcbLettuce = new JCheckBox("Lettuce");
    private JCheckBox jcbSpinach = new JCheckBox("Spinach");
    private JCheckBox jcbOnion = new JCheckBox("Onion");
    private JCheckBox jcbPickles = new JCheckBox("Pickles");
    private JCheckBox jcbTomatoes = new JCheckBox("Tomatoes");
    private JCheckBox jcbPeppers = new JCheckBox("Peppers");
    private JCheckBox jcbMayo = new JCheckBox("Mayo");
    private JCheckBox jcbMustard = new JCheckBox("Mustard");
    private JCheckBox jcbDressing = new JCheckBox("Italian Dressing");

    public Subway() {
        //name
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(24, 1));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Enter Name"));
        p1.add(jtfname);
        //size
        p1.add(new JLabel("Select a size"));
        p1.add(jcbSize);
        //bread
        p1.add(new JLabel("Select a Bread"));
        p1.add(jcbBread);
        //type
        p1.add(new JLabel("What type of sub would you like?"));
        p1.add(jcbtype);
        //cheese
        p1.add(new JLabel("Select a cheese"));
        p1.add(jcbcheese);
        //toasted
        p1.add(new JLabel("Would you like it toasted?"));
        p1.add(jcbToasted);
        //toppings
        p1.add(new JLabel("Select your toppings"));
        p1.add(jcbLettuce);
        p1.add(jcbSpinach);
        p1.add(jcbPickles);
        p1.add(jcbOnion);
        p1.add(jcbTomatoes);
        p1.add(jcbPeppers);
        p1.add(jcbMayo);
        p1.add(jcbMustard);
        p1.add(jcbDressing);
        // BUTTON PANEL
        JPanel p5 = new JPanel();
        p5.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p5, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        p5.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());// KEEPS THEM HORIZONTAL
        p5.add(jbtExit);
        p5.add(jbtAnother);
        p5.add(jbtSubmit);
        // ADDING PANELS AND WHERE THEY GO
        add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);// TOP
        add(p5, BorderLayout.SOUTH);// BOTTOM
        // SETTING INVISIBLE BORDERS AROUND PANELS TO SPACE THEM OUT
        p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        p5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        // EXIT BUTTON LISTENER
        jbtExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                System.exit(0);

            }
        });
        // Another order BUTTON LISTENER
        jbtAnother.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                makeASandwich();


            }
        });
        // SUBMIT BUTTON LISTENER
        jbtSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                makeASandwich();
                for (Sandwich s : Sandwich.order) {
                    String Order = " ";
                    Order = jtfname.getText() + "\n"
                            + "\nSize: " + s.getSize()
                            + "\nType of Sub: " + s.getName()
                            + "\nBread: " + s.getBread()
                            + "\nCheese: " + s.getCheese()
                            + "\nToasted? " + s.getToasted()
                            + "\n\n---Next Order---";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Order);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void makeASandwich() {
        Sandwich sandwich = new Sandwich(jcbtype.getItemAt(jcbtype.getSelectedIndex()));
        sandwich.setBread(jcbBread.getItemAt(jcbBread.getSelectedIndex()));
        sandwich.setCheese(jcbcheese.getItemAt(jcbcheese.getSelectedIndex()));
        sandwich.setToasted(jcbToasted.getItemAt(jcbToasted.getSelectedIndex()));
        sandwich.setSize(jcbSize.getItemAt(jcbSize.getSelectedIndex()));
        // sandwich.setPrice(jcbtype.getItemAt(jcbtype.getSelectedIndex()));
        Sandwich.order.add(sandwich);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subway frame = new Subway();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("SUBWAY");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600, 750);
    }// ENDOFMAIN
}// ENDOFCLASS

class HoldOrder {

    public static List<Sandwich> order = new ArrayList<Sandwich>();
}

class Sandwich {

    String bread = "";
    String sandwichName = "";
    String cheese = "";
    String size = "";
    String toasted = "";
    private double total = 0;
    public static List<Sandwich> order = new ArrayList<Sandwich>();

    public Sandwich(String typeOfSandwich) {
        sandwichName = typeOfSandwich;
        //switch(setPrice) { 
        //case "BLT":
        //  total += 3.00D;
        //   break;
        //  case "Turkey Bacon":
        //   total += 3.50D;
        //  break;
        //}
    }

    public String getName() {
        return sandwichName;
    }

    public void setBread(String s) {
        bread = s;
    }

    public String getBread() {
        return bread;
    }

    public void setCheese(String s) {
        cheese = s;
    }

    public String getCheese() {
        return cheese;
    }

    public void setSize(String s) {
        size = s;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setToasted(String s) {
        toasted = s;
    }

    public String getToasted() {
        return toasted;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList <of certain type>` is just a container (like ordinary array).  For example, you can create a class `Order` and store objects of this class in your Arraylist.  Then when required you will transfer string representations of your objects to JOptionPane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You post a lot of codes, so, instead, I create a demo for you:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author Azad
 */
public class ShowListDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private java.util.List<String> list;

    public ShowListDemo(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JButton show = new JButton("Show List Content");
        show.addActionListener(this);
        p.add(show);

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("infromation one");
        list.add("information two");
        list.add("information three");

        add(p);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String...args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
              new ShowListDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       String  s = "" ;
        for(String a : list)
            s += a +"\n";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, s);//@Mad programmer's recommended, I can't refuse :)
    }
}
```

---

Also create a button for adding elements to the list, however, I prefer `JList` instead option pane, it's more comfortable.

Comment: I hope that means you're suggesting that the user should use a `JList` on the `JOptionPane`, cause that would be one of my suggestions ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Actually I didn't mean that, but sounds good idea.

Comment: It's a nit-pick, but I would highly recommend that you pass `this` as the first parameter to `JOptionPane` as I can't abide dialogs that popup in relation to the component they were instantiated from - especially in a multi-screen environment :P

Comment: I think the use of a `JList` or `JTable` over the use of `JOptionPane` is also a good idea, but may be beyond the scope of what the OP is looking for

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I remmember I used this way in one of my assignments, till know I don't know why I get `0.8` on `3` :D

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm supposed to use JOptionPane for the assignment but I don't think it is a requirement.

Comment: @Kyle That's what I figured ;)

Comment: @Kyle: You're welcome, I noticed you didn't accept any answer of your questions(I don't mean to accept mine off course), do you know how to accept an answer, it's easy, see this link please:[**stackoverflow.com/about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: @Azad Sorry, about not accepting.  I didn't know how. I updated my code and question.  Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: @Kyle: I am really want to sleep know, sorry, and be sure I will not answer the EDIT question as you must ask a new question about that maybe you get answer, a lost try to post a brief description with a small area of compiled code :)  Sorry for that, but [ask another question about that.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could format the `List` of `String`s as HTML and allow the HTML support in Swing to render it, something like [Display array in JOptionPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926545/display-array-in-joptionpane/13926750#13926750), [JOptionPane Multidimensional Array output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824033/joptionpane-multidimensional-array-output/15824067#15824067) and [JOptionPane displaying HTML problems in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702689/joptionpane-displaying-html-problems-in-java/12702858#12702858) for example

Something that many people forget, the second parameter to a `JOptionPane` is a `Object`, the `JOptionPane` allows you to pass a `Component` which it will use as it's primary display.  This means you could display a `JTable` or `JList` for example.

Check out [JOptionPane displaying HTML problems in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702689/joptionpane-displaying-html-problems-in-java/12702858#12702858) for an example